# Wordpress, Gantry Framework, Child Theme?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks

Does anyone have experience with Gantry Framework?

I am wondering if it is possible to create a child theme based off of the default? Where would I put my css file and can I build off of the current css instead of starting from scratch while still separating my css from the default theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Child Theme is very easy.

All you need to do is create a directory in your theme directory, and name it something like "Gantry-child". Inside that folder, add a file called "style.css". Once this is done, you just need to add the Theme Information that tells Wordpress the Child Theme's Name, Author, and Parent Theme.

Inside the new style.css, add:

```
/*
Theme Name:     Gantry Child
Template:       rt_gantry_wp
*/
```

The most important part that lets Wordpress know that this is a child of the Gantry Theme is the "Template" section. This is the name of the PARENT directory in your Themes folder.

What this will do is create a new theme that inherits all of the parent theme's functions. If you also want to inherit the existing parent theme stylesheet, add to style.css:

```
@import url("../rt_gantry_wp/style.css");
```

Hopefully this should get you started. Once that's done, you can add your own header, footer, index, functions, or anything else you can think of to extend the parent theme's functionality.

Hopefully this helps get you started.

Comment: Much thanks! Seems simple enough. As a side note, I believe Gantry only allows stylesheet changes for child themes due to the nature of the framework.

Comment: Duly noted. I've never worked with Gantry before, so if it somehow overrides Wordpress' usual treatment of child themes, then ignore my comments about header/footer/index/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [usual process of creating a WordPress child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) (create a directory, with proper style.css and functions.php), Gantry requires [a specific procedure](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/theme-development/create-child-theme-wordpress).
You'll need to copy two files from the parent directory to the child theme directory, keeping the structure:

```
/gantry/theme.yaml
```

and

```
/includes/theme.php
```

Then, edit the copied `theme.yaml`: the *parent* must be your parent theme directory name.

On the `theme.php`, select all text and replace with this:

```
// Initialize theme stream.
$gantry['platform']->set(
    'streams.gantry-theme.prefixes',
    array('' => array(
        "gantry-themes://{$gantry['theme.name']}/custom",
        "gantry-themes://{$gantry['theme.name']}",
        "gantry-themes://{$gantry['theme.name']}/common",
        "gantry-themes://{$gantry['theme.parent']}",
        "gantry-themes://{$gantry['theme.parent']}/common"
    ))
);
```

As for css, you must create this file, within your child theme directory:

```
/custom/scss/custom.scss
```

It can be formatted in either SCSS or CSS, and will override the theme's core style sheet files.

Comment: As I'm a newbie here, I was not able to post [this link](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/tutorials/adding-a-custom-style-sheet), regarding the css file.